# White border around the video

Tags: html, css

I can't get rid of the top and bottom white border of the video. Video is set on *width: 100%;* so there's no border on the left and right. When I set * (universal sizing) using *margin: 0;* everything bumps together, even two cards (kartica and kartica2), but I want them separated a bit.

Then if I set *margin: 0;* all the other pages bump together. Is there any way I can edit this with one selector(video selector is kartica2)?

This CSS sheet is universal, but for that specific page, content is at the top.

```css
/*Naloga 1*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*universal box-sizing*/
}

body,
html {
  margin-left: 0px;
  /*zunanji odmik*/
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: #b3b3ff;
  /*hex value*/
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  /*drugace nastavi auto browser*/
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  /*glava na vrhu strani ko se premikamo navzdol*/
  top: 0;
}

#h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  color: #6600ff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  /*drugace nastavi auto browser*/
}

#h2 {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  color: #6600ff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

#ul {
  background-color: #6600ff;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*oznake v seznamu*/
  margin: 0;
  /*to remove browser default settings*/
  padding: 0;
  /*to remove browser default settings*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /* ce bi b boxsu bilo prevec vsebine*/
  background-color: #1a1aff;
  /*barva navigacije*/
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  /*kot block elements naredi celotno areo clickable-ne samo tekst*/
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*skrijes podcrtano besedilo*/
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #000033;
  /*barva ozadja ko se postavimo z misko*/
}

.vsebina {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.kartica {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.kartica2 {
  background-color: white;
  /*kartica za video*/
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}


/*naloga 2*/

.n2 {
  width: 100%;
}


/*video*/

#n21 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/*zunanji odmik clankov*/

.n22 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.n23 {
  text-align: center;
}


/*pripis pod sliko*/


/*naloga 3*/

#h3 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  color: #6600ff;
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  /*ker so 3, ce bi bile 4 - 25%*/
  padding: 5px;
  /* razmaki med karticami*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  /*navigation bar to the content*/
}


/* Clear floats after the columns, postavi 3x2 */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Responsive columns */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

.slika3 {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.opis {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: scroll;
  /*Drsni trak*/
}


/*Naloga 4*/

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=text]:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 2px solid #555;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: none;
  /* prepreci spreminjanje polja*/
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="si">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tilenova spletna stran</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>
  <div class="sticky">

    <h1 id="h1">Tilenova spletna stran </h1>

    <ul id="ul">
      <li><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
      <li><a href="ponudba.html">Ponudba</a></li>
      <li><a href="anketa.html">Anketa</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://estudij.um.si" target="_blank">Vaje</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="vsebina">
    <div class="kartica">
      <h2 id="h2">O meni</h2>
      <p id="n21">Sem <a href="mailto:tilen.socic@gmail.com">Tilen Sočič</a> in študiram na <b>Fakulteti za elektrotehniko, računalništvo in informatiko</b>.</p>
      <p id="n21">To je moja spletna stran, ki je nastala pri predmetu <u>Osnove svetovnega spleta</u>.</p>
      <p id="n21">V prostem času se ukvarjam s športom in modifikacijo računalniskih delov.</p><br />


      <!-- odstrani figure in odmiki se odstranijo -->
      <img class="n22" src="images/galaksija.jpg" alt="galaksija">
      <figcaption class="n23">Slika nočnega neba</figcaption>


    </div>

    <div class="kartica2">
      <h2 id="h2">Video: Spreminjanje mehurčka v led</h2>


      <video class="n2" controls>
         <source src="Videos/Mehurcek.mp4">
        </video>


      <p id="n21">Video iz strani <a href="https://videos.pexels.com/videos/bubble-turning-into-ice-855627" target="_blank">PEXELS VIDEOS</a></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `#h2` ID, you need to add a `margin-bottom: 0;`

```
#h2 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #6600ff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0; /*Added*/
}
```

and also `#n21`, here add a `margin-top: 0;`

```
#n21 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0; /*Added*/
}
```

Let me know if that helps! [Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/RqKZKV) you have a codepen if you want to test it!